# How can I disable Chrome pop ups?

Tags: javascript, cypress

[image: Chrome pop-up]

How can I disable this pop-up with JS/Cypress code?

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if Chrome offered a way to disable that confirmation dialog.  At the very least you'd likely need to write your own Chrome extension/plugin to do that.

Comment: Is there a way that at least I could go back to the previous page? I tried to write cy.go(-1), but because cypress says that it is "waiting for new page to load" it doesnt even proceed to the cy.go code

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid Chrome opening alert dialog but you can deal with them with cypress:

```
cy.on('window:alert', (buttonText) => {
  return false; //clicks on cancel 
});
```

or with confirmation dialog:

```
cy.on('window:confirm', (buttonText) => {
  return false;
});
```